# 'GuideSpider' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project that I want to use to scrape some websites.
When I try to save all the information in a MySQL db the error in the title pops out.
I read everywhere and I found out that it is a "list" problem, probably connected to the items[] list...
Can you please help me understand what this error means and where I should fix the code?
Please also explain why because I want to understand. Thank you so much.

**Spider Code:**

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


from gscrape.items import GscrapeItem

class GuideSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Dplay"
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.examplea.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=108&order=desc&page=1"
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("forumdisplay.php.*f=108.*page=")), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        sites = hxs.select('//div')
        for site in sites:
            item = GscrapeItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('a[@class="threadcolor"]/text()').extract()
            item['guide_url'] = site.select('a[@class="threadcolor"]/@href').extract()
            item['subject'] = site.select('./text()[1]').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

**Pipeline Code:**

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from string import join
from scrapy import log
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

import MySQLdb.cursors

class GscrapePipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['guide_url']:
                item['guide_url'] = "http://www.example.com/forums/" + join(item['guide_url'])
                return item
        else:
            raise DropItem()

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # @@@ hardcoded db settings
        # TODO: make settings configurable through settings
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb',
            db='prova',
            host='127.0.0.1',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode=True
        )

    def process_item(self, spider, item):
        # run db query in thread pool
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
        query.addErrback(self.handle_error)

        return item

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    # create record if doesn't exist.
    # all this block run on it's own thread
        tx.execute("select * from prova where guide_url = %s", item['guide_url'])
        result = tx.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            tx.execute(\
            "insert into prova (title, guide_url, subject) "
            "values (%s, %s, %s)",
            (item['title'],
             item['guide_url'],
             item['subject']
                ))
            log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

Error: **exceptions.TypeError: 'GuideSpider' object is not subscriptable (line 47) pipelines.py**

Comment: Can you include the entire stacktrace with all the error lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item):

```
process_item(item, spider)
```

I mean in your pipeline:

```
def process_item(self, spider, item):
```

you have wrong order of parameters, this meaning that you pass to `_conditional_insert` your spider and not the item.

Learn to us debugger. Install [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/) and put on line 47 (before the offending line) this:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

When the program reaches the breakpoint, you will be able to see values of the variables, calling the method manually and see the backtrace.

Comment: The ipdb link is broken. If you want to install ipdb for python 3 This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242207/install-ipdb-for-python-3#17242289 worked for me.