# Install ipdb for Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipdb

I installed [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) using `pip`, but I am still getting

`ImportError: No module named ipdb`.

Do I have to do something else to bring this module in? Of course, I `import ipdb` at the top of my file as well. My thinking is this: I have Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed. Pip installed `ipdb` to the Python 2.7 directory, but the Python module I am running is using Python 3. I think this is the issue, but how can I resolve it, so that `ipdb` can be used with my Python 3 module? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262143/3694

> 1. Install package `python3-setuptools`: run `sudo aptitude install python3-setuptools`, this will give you the command `easy_install3`.
> 2. Install pip using Python 3's setuptools: run `sudo easy_install3 pip`, this will give you the command `pip-3.2`.
> 3. Install your PyPI packages: run `sudo pip-3.2 install <package>` (installing python packages into your base system requires root, of
>      course).

Comment: Thanks, I searched around but did not see the one you are referencing. Much appreciated.